# Identify vectors being a multiple of another in rectangular matrix

Tags: numpy, precision

Given a nxm matrix (n > m) of integers, I'd like to identify rows that are a multiple of a **single** other row, so not a linear combination of multiple other rows.
I could scale all rows to their length and find unique rows, but that is prone to numerical issues on floating points and would also not detect vectors being opposite (pointing in the other directon) of each other.
Any ideas?

Example

```py
A = array([[-1, -1,  0,  0],
       [-1, -1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0, -1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0,  1,  1],
       [-1,  1, -1,  0],
       [-1,  1,  0,  0],
       [-1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  1],
       [ 0, -1,  1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  1, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 1, -1,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  0]])
```

For example Rows 0 and -3 just point in the opposite direction (multiply one by -1 to make them equal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normalize each row dividing it by its GCD:

```
import numpy as np

def normalize(a):
    return a // np.gcd.reduce(a, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

And you can define a distance that considers opposite vectors as equal:

```
def distance(a, b):
    equal = np.all(a == b) or np.all(a == -b)
    return 0 if equal else 1
```

Then you can use standard clustering methods:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, fcluster

def cluster(a):
    norm_a = normalize(a)
    distances = pdist(norm_a, metric=distance)
    return fcluster(linkage(distances), t=0.5)
```

For example:

```
>>> A = np.array([( 1,  2,  3,  4),
...               ( 0,  2,  4,  8),
...               (-1, -2, -3, -4),
...               ( 0,  1,  2,  4),
...               (-1,  2, -3,  4),
...               ( 2, -4,  6, -8)])
>>> cluster(A)
array([2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Interpretation: cluster 1 is formed by rows 4 and 5, cluster 2 by rows 0 and 2, and cluster 3 by rows 1 and 3.

Comment: I like the `gcd` approach. Will combine it with a `sign` operation, so the first non-zero element of `a` in `normalize` is positive. Then after `normalize` I can just sort the matrix and don't need to enumerate all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that inner product of two normalized linearly dependent vectors gives 1 or -1, so the code could look like this:

```py
>>> A_normalized = (A.T/np.linalg.norm(A, axis=-1)).T
>>> M = np.absolute(np.einsum('ix,jx->ij', A_normalized, A_normalized))
>>> i, j = np.where(np.isclose(M, 1))
>>> i, j = i[i < j], j[i < j] # Remove repetitions
>>> print(i, j)
```

output: `[ 0  2  3  6  7  9 11 13] [27 25 23 22 21 17 16 15]`

Comment: This technically works, but I'm afraid of the floating point operations and the isclose for comparison.